# How to check if mouse is over an element? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to check if mouse is over an element?

I moving element to cursor position and I need to check if mouse is over an another element. How to do it?

```
<div class="dragged"></div> // I can move it
<div class="dropped"></div> // Need to drop here
```

```js
$('.dragged').mousemove(function(e) {
   ...
   if($(".dropped").is(":hover")) { // of course doesn't work
        ...
   }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI draggable/droppable you can check the `ui` parameter of the `drop` event: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: Maybe you could use .mouseover ? http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I don't use it, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

You may try like this:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    if ($('#Test').is(':hover')) {
        alert('Test');
    }
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AyAZx/573/)**

Comment: I moving element (.dragged) to cursor position and it always will be hover.

Answer (score 3):

One valid approach is to "flag" the .dropped tag element when the mouse is enter.
Finally, when you move .dragged, you can check is .dropped has the tag you put into them.

```
$('.dropped').hover(function() { 
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});

$('.dragged').mousemove(function(e) {
  ...
  if($(".dropped").hasClass(".hovered")) {
    ...
 }
});
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
  var hovred=null;
    $('.dropped').mouseenter(function(e) {
      hovred=$(this);
     });

$('.dropped').mouseleave(function(e) {
  hovred=null;
 });
$('.dropped').mousemove(function(e) {
   ...
   if($(this)==hovred && hovred != null) { 
    //do your stuff here man
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
 var $container = $('.container');
 $container.mouseenter(function(e) {
  //do something
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will not work because near to mouse already have element. (dragged)

Comment: Another fun bug: Safari generates `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events that consider the `box-shadow` part of the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call_mouseover()
{ 
  alert("mouse is over on the div");
}
function call_mouseout()
{
 alert("mouse out from the div");

}
</script>


<div class="dragged" onmouseover="call_mouseover();" onmouseout="call_mouseout();"></div>
<div class="dropped" ></div> // Need to drop here
```